# Grails 2.2.1 is not reading plugin Config file

Tags: grails, upgrade, config

I have an app and a plugin built with Grails 2.1.1 that i upgraded to 2.2.1 and I am running into a weird issue. My application started blowing up all over because configuration values defined in my app `Config.groovy` all of a sudden resolve to `groovy.Util.ConfigObject` instead of their actual values. This is part 1 of the problem, part 2 is that in my app, I define in my app's `Config.groovy`

```
grails.config.defaults.locations = [
    "classpath:DemoPluginConfig.groovy",
]
```

`DemoPluginConfig.groovy` contains this property

```
oo.memcached.timeout=400000
```

and the `DemoPluginConfig.groovy` file is in the `src/java` folder of my Demo plugin.
I have a memcache service where i am trying to set that timeout property once the service is ready:

```
def void afterPropertiesSet() {

        ConnectionFactoryBuilder cfb = new ConnectionFactoryBuilder()
        def config = grailsApplication.config;
        def operationTimeOut = config.oo.memcached.timeout
        cfb.setOpTimeout(timeOut)

    }
```

grails run-app blows up at this point with error:

```
Caused by MissingMethodException: No signature of method: net.spy.memcached.ConnectionFactoryBuilder.setOpTimeout() is applicable for argument types: (groovy.util.ConfigObject) values: [[:]]
Possible solutions: setOpTimeout(long)
->>   55 | unwrap                          in org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     46 | call                            in org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite
|     45 | defaultCall . . . . . . . . . . in org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray
|    108 | call                            in org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite
|    116 | call . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     20 | afterPropertiesSet              in com.millennialmedia.ui.core.MemcachedService
|   1514 | invokeInitMethods . . . . . . . in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory
|   1452 | initializeBean                  in     ''
|    519 | doCreateBean . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    122 | doCreateBean                    in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory
|    456 | createBean . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory
|    271 | resolveInnerBean                in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver
|    126 | resolveValueIfNecessary . . . . in     ''
|   1360 | applyPropertyValues             in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory
|   1118 | populateBean . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
```

If i try to run grails run-app a couple more time it starts up successfully but the app blows up on loading a page with another `groovy.Util.ConfigObject` is not serializable error. Step by step debugging before the app blows up shows that by the time we get to the `setOptTimeOut` line, `grailsApplication.config` only contains config options from my app's Config.groovy, as if the values from the plugin `DemoPLuginConfig.groovy` were just ignored.

Reverting back to 2.1.1 brings everything back to normal. At this point I have no idea where to look.

Comment: I had a similar issue but in reverse - my plugin copies its conf file into the client's conf dir and after running grails upgrade (2.2.1) the plugin's conf was getting read preferentially over the client's version. So what I'm seeing is grails upgrade is stuffing the classpath resolution and/or ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using `operationTimeOut` instead of `timeOut` below

```
cfb.setOpTimeout(timeOut)
```

Comment: it's actually set to operationTimeout in the code but that's not the reason the error happens

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your Groovy configuration in *grails-app/conf* instead of *src/java*. Then, see if you can reproduce your error on a consistent basis.

If all fails, *grails clean* may prevail.

Hope it helps

Comment: I'll try that and let you know